# Unable to initialize SparkSession on jupyter Notebook

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm beginning to work on Spark, and after struggling to install everything on my computer I thought that it would be much more clever to simply use a docker image with everything configured.
So I started to use this docker image https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/pyspark-notebook

But whenever I try to just create my session like this :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Test').getOrCreate()
```

I keep receiving this error

```
    Py4JJavaErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-3b12a82b5b9c> in <module>
      1 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
----> 2 spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Test').getOrCreate()

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in getOrCreate(self)
    226                             sparkConf.set(key, value)
    227                         # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
--> 228                         sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    229                     # Do not update `SparkConf` for existing `SparkContext`, as it's shared
    230                     # by all sessions.

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py in getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    382         with SparkContext._lock:
    383             if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 384                 SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    385             return SparkContext._active_spark_context
    386 

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    144         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    145         try:
--> 146             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
    147                           conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    148         except:

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py in _do_init(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    207 
    208         # Create the Java SparkContext through Py4J
--> 209         self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
    210         # Reset the SparkConf to the one actually used by the SparkContext in JVM.
    211         self._conf = SparkConf(_jconf=self._jsc.sc().conf())

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py in _initialize_context(self, jconf)
    319         Initialize SparkContext in function to allow subclass specific initialization
    320         """
--> 321         return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
    322 
    323     @classmethod

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1566 
   1567         answer = self._gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1568         return_value = get_return_value(
   1569             answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
   1570 

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.sparkproject.jetty.http.MimeTypes
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.<init>(GzipHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.ServerInfo.addHandler(JettyUtils.scala:485)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI.$anonfun$bind$3(WebUI.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI.$anonfun$bind$3$adapted(WebUI.scala:147)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI.bind(WebUI.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$new$11(SparkContext.scala:486)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$new$11$adapted(SparkContext.scala:486)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:486)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

There seems to have some issues with Jetty but I really don't get what could be the problem.

If someone could point me to the right direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found out that the issue was related to my computer.
I have a recent Mac Book with M1 processor, and some problem seems to occur with this architecture.
I switched to another image https://github.com/sakuraiyuta/docker-stacks/tree/master/pyspark-notebook (forked from my initial image) which is updated to match my architecture and it seems to work fine now.